# Dockerfile django & mysql

Tags: mysql, django, docker

I'm trying to create a docker environment for my django project

my dockerfile :

```
 FROM python:3
 ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
 RUN apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev
 RUN mkdir /config  
 ADD /config/requirements.txt /config/  
 RUN pip install -r /config/requirements.txt
 RUN mkdir /src
 WORKDIR /src
```

my docker-compose :

```
 version: '3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
       MYSQL_USER: root
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
       MYSQL_DATABASE: ProjetDjango
     container_name: mysql01
     restart: always
   nginx:
     image: nginx:1.13-alpine
     container_name: nginx01
     ports:
       - "8000:8000"
     volumes:
       - ./project:/src
       - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
     depends_on:
       - web
   web:
     build: .
     container_name: django01
     command: bash -c "python3 manage.py makemigrations && python3 manage.py migrate && python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput && gunicorn hello_django.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000"
     depends_on:
       - db
     volumes:
       - ./project:/src
     expose:
       - "8000"
     restart: always
```

my settings.py :

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'ProjetDjango',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'root',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1', 
    'PORT': '3306',
 }
}
```

I've got this error while running : docker-compose up

django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2006, 'Can\'t connect to MySQL server on \'127.0.0.1\' (111 "Connection refused")')
django01 exited with code 1

I've been working on this issue for 2 days now and didn't find a response that solve it!

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you link your db service to your web service in docker so you must use your db service name instead of your database server ip for connecting database :

```
db:
    image: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: db_of_my_project

web:
    build: .
    container_name: django01
    command: ...
    links:
        - db
    volumes:
        - ./project:/src
    expose:
        - "8000"
    restart: always
```

and your database configuration:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'ProjetDjango',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'db',  #  database container name
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: (This answer will work equally well without the `links:` section.)